# Role duplication and execution, passing multiple variable structure for arguments that can have multiple entries

Tags: ansible

I am trying come up with a way to pass multiple variables to the same field in a role but not having any luck getting it to work using the Role duplication and execution method I've been using. As an example I want an SLB Server to have multiple ports assigned to it using the port_number variable. I'm new to Ansible so making some rookie mistakes like the code below (port_number: "80", port_number: "8080" returns duplicate entry so only uses the first) but I have tried just about every syntax I have found examples for and nothing is working right. The end result is basically having test3 with both of the port_number: entries assigned to it but at this point I'm not even sure it's possible doing it this way or if I have to run a separate module after the fact to add the entries. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
---
- name: Deploy A10 config
  connection: local
  hosts: all
  roles:
  - role: server
    vars:
     name: "test1"
     fqdn_name: "test1.test.domain.net"
     health_check: "TCP-8080-HALFOPEN"
     port_number: "80"


  - { role: server, vars: { name: "test2", fqdn_name: "test2.test.domain.net", port_number: "8080" }}
  - { role: server, vars: { name: "test3", fqdn_name: "test3.test.domain.net", port_number: "80", port_number: "8080" }}

---
- name: Test server create
  a10_slb_server:
    a10_host: "10.1.1.1"
    a10_username: "admin"
    a10_password: "admin"
    a10_port: "443"
    a10_protocol: "https"
    state: present
    name: "{{ name }}"
    fqdn_name: "{{ fqdn_name }}"
    port_list:
      - port_number: "{{ port_number }}"
```

Comment: i revoke my answer, because i didnt recognize you are using roles. i dont suggest using "with_items" along with roles, but as a separate task.

Comment: Thanks for the help and although I did spend some time tracking down why it didn't work, I learned some things along the way and at this point in my Ansible journey that is gold! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code *vars* is [**dictionary**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html). The keys in a dictionary must be unique.

```
vars:
 name: "test1"
 fqdn_name: "test1.test.domain.net"
 health_check: "TCP-8080-HALFOPEN"
 port_number: "80"
```

YAML resolves the duplication of the keys simply by overriding the value. This expression

```
vars: { name: "test3", fqdn_name: "test3.test.domain.net", port_number: "80", port_number: "8080" }
```

would give

```
"vars": {
    "fqdn_name": "test3.test.domain.net", 
    "name": "test3", 
    "port_number": "8080"
}
```

In your code *port_list* is **list**. It's a list of dictionaries. This seems to be the proper way to declare multiple port numbers.

```
port_list:
  - port_number: "80"
  - port_number: "8080"
```

In serialized format

```
port_list: [{port_number: "80"}, {port_number: "8080"}]
```

But, in your code *role: server* it's not clear how these variables are used in the role. It is necessary to review the role to learn how to submit the data.

---

For example:

```
- role: server
  vars:
    name: "test1"
    fqdn_name: "test1.test.domain.net"
    health_check: "TCP-8080-HALFOPEN"
    port_number1: "80"
    port_number2: "8080"

--
- name: Test server create
  a10_slb_server:
    a10_host: "10.1.1.1"
    a10_username: "admin"
    a10_password: "admin"
    a10_port: "443"
    a10_protocol: "https"
    state: present
    name: "{{ name }}"
    fqdn_name: "{{ fqdn_name }}"
    port_list:
      - port_number: "{{ port_number1 }}"
      - port_number: "{{ port_number2 }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and your patience with a beginner. The role: server simply adds a new server entry on the load balancer with any number of ports assigned to it (we have one with 15 ports assigned!). The input really is only name, fqdn_name and ports assigned which then creates a server entry on the LB.

Comment: Looking at your example does bring up an interesting point though. Not that this would be a clean way of doing it but conceptually I could create up to 15+ port_number entries in the play and then just use the ones I need as variables in the main playbook. Not the most elegant way but until I get a better handle on Ansible it may well do the trick. Will let you know and thanks again.

Comment: Well I should have known that wouldn't work when I typed it but getting a little turned around on this. I am wondering if this is just a matter of running the initial server module takes one argument and any further entries that need to be added require a separate module ran against the now created server entry. This would be similar to how creating a VM from a template would then require an additional tasks ran to add another disk to the server. I'm almost positive multiple variables can be passed but for the life of me cannot figure it out.